# How to get the InputState to pass the same in transaction builder

Tags: corda

I am trying to build a application for which I have to take the Inputstate and generate the Outputstate when one of the fields of state is changing:

Based on documentaion, I came to know that I need to use addInputState

TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(ourStateAndRef)
                .addOutputState(outputState, TemplateContract.ID)
                .addCommand(command);

Where ourStateAndRef is of type:

StateRef ourStateRef = new StateRef(SecureHash.sha256("DummyTransactionHash"), 0);
StateAndRef ourStateAndRef = getServiceHub().toStateAndRef(ourStateRef);

But how do I get the value of "DummyTransaction" or transaction hash which I want to update?

Say one transaction executed between party a and party b for value 10, now I want to update the value to 5 and make the old transaction to historic/consumed and make the new one to Unconsumed.

Is there a way to get the transaction hash or transaction id related to one of the past updates

Answer (score 0):

In Corda, states are stored in the Vault. It's the states stored here that you'll be using as input states into your transaction.

You can read [here](https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html) how to query the Vault for states.